# Finding values inside getter function with string methods

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

```
var grid = [
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 'W', 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]
];

function Piece (position) {
 this.position = position;
 Object.defineProperty(this, 'color', {
  get: function(position) {
  var hold = position, 
      holdTwo = position.substring(0,1);
 if(holdTwo === 'W') {
   return 'White';
 } 
}
});
}

var pieceOne = new Piece(grid[1][2]);
console.log(pieceOne.color);
```

I'm trying to define the property color with the getter method, but whenever I try to use .substring or .indexOf, it always says that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. Is there any way to check the first letter of a string inside a getter function?

Answer (score 0):

getter doen't get any arguments.Just remove the argument `position` and use `this.position` instead of `position`.

```
get: function() {
    var hold = this.position, 
        holdTwo = this.position.substring(0,1);
    if(holdTwo === 'W') {
    return 'White';
    } 
}
```